# Strange values when debugging

Tags: c++, debugging, variables, math, trigonometry

When I was doing some debugging I noticed there were some strange values being stored, **have a look at the "convX" variable here** which should get the value of about 9.95 but turns out as 6.95*10^-310: http://gyazo.com/5109fc563e1e87939adea84ea87f3d88
Are variables not initialized to zero? Is that the problem?

The values seem to be fine (a couple of rows down) when doing the function call though, but are those values the ones fed as arguments into the function?: http://gyazo.com/b26b4bedbcc0557cd53ade5fe59827f8

Comment: Please don't post links to code in questions.  Post the code in the question. Variables are not initialized to zero.

Comment: Local variables are not implicitly initialized in general. Some environments may initialize them to 0 (or some other value) in certain circumstances, but you cannot rely on that happening.

Comment: @mah Why aren't they initialized to zero? Doesn't that make the most sense?

Comment: The language specification doesn't require them to be initialized... and if you look at your own code, you can see it would actually be wasted effort to have initialized them to 0 since you're just going to immediately set them to a new value anyway! Since local variables (typically, but not by requirement) live on your stack, it's much easier for the system to let the initial value be "whatever happens to be there". That's free, but initializing them to a specific value requires one or more instructions.

Comment: @mah Okay I see, so if there happens to be a "135" in a part of memory which is allocated to a new variable that new variable gets the value 135?

Comment: @AxelKennedal-TechTutor exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Local variables of primitive data type are not initialized by default in C++. Strange values that you see are called as Garbage Values.